# how to change default language when using Browser-provided speech BotFramework

Tags: google-chrome, botframework, web-chat

I want to enable speech in Web Chat. According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-webchat-speech?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#enable-speech-services), it is possible. And I did it. But it's English. I want to change to the Japanese. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
locale="ja-JP" webSpeechPonyfillFactory={xxx}
```